# Sending JPEG via C Socket needs 300ms Delay for Firefox

Tags: c, sockets, firefox, http-headers

I'm writing a program to stream single JPEG images on a Linux box from a camera to a locally running copy of Firefox. The JPEGs load fine with wget and Chrome, but Firefox was only loading the first 64k (confirmed via Firebug).  I finally got Firefox to display the entire image, if I broke the transmission into 64000 bytes blocks, and added a 250ms delay between blocks. This of course delays the transmission, and I'm trying to actually get a through put of at least 2-5 frames a second.

Why does Firefox need a delay between blocks? Why does Firefox need the image broken into <64k blocks to begin with?

Neither step was needed for Chrome or wget. In general the images are < 128k.

Here is the code block in question:

```
    int bytes = jpeg_size[out_buffer];
    int start = 0;
    buffer_active = true;
    sprintf(buffer, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\nVary: Accept-Encoding\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\nConnection: Close\n\n" );

    n = write(newsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");

    while (bytes > 0) {
        int size = bytes > 64000 ? 64000 : bytes;
        n = send(newsockfd, &(jpeg[out_buffer][start]), size, 0); 
        if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");

        bytes -= n;
        start += n;
        if (bytes > 0) // Added for Firefox compatibility
            usleep(250000);
    }
    buffer_active = false;
```

And here is the function that initiates the socket:

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (sockfd < 0)  
    error("ERROR opening socket");
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
portno = new_portno;
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
            sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)  
    error("ERROR on binding");
listen(sockfd,5);
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
buffer_active = false;
current_buffer = -1; 
die_status = false;
newsockfd = -1;
```

Followed by:

```
newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
        (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
        &clilen);
if (newsockfd < 0) 
    error("ERROR on accept");
bzero(buffer,1024);
n = read(newsockfd,buffer,1024);
```

Comment: HEADER: Content-Length

Comment: I've actually tried the Content-Length in the past, as it was also a first thought of mine. However, Firefox does not respond any better knowing the length of data coming.  I re-added it to the code above, and I could not increase the block size, or decrease the delay... Thanks though for the tip.